# How to setup application icon that shows up in Alt-Tab dialog when switching tasks on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, icons, wxpython

How do I setup icon, for `wxpython` application on `Windows`, that shows up in the `Alt-Tab` dialog when I'm switching between applications?

The application icon in the menu bar and the corner of the running app shows my icon but when I switch between applications using Alt-Tab I can see the default square with blue outline icon.

Do I need to do something extra for my icon to show up in Alt-Tab dialog or does my icon have to include a special resolution?

In my class initializer I setup icon :

```
class A(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,-1,title,size=(265,434))
        favicon = wx.Icon('C:\source\python\gui\gf.ico',
                           wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO, 16,16)
        wx.Frame.SetIcon(self,favicon)
```

Comment: I think you need to fix the indentation of your last two lines.

Comment: fixed, I had it correct in my file, copy/paste issue

Comment: Which version of windows are you using? I'm using windows7 and your code works fine. Notice that if you run the script you actually run the python interpreter so it will show python icon on task bar. Though it shows the right one while alt-tab pressing. If you turn it into a executable by using like cx_Freeze then each will be the right one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```
self.icon = wx.Icon(fn, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO)
self.SetIcon(self.icon)
```

where the icon in fn has several resolutions (16, 32, and 48, I think).

Looks like you at least want to change

```
    wx.Frame.SetIcon(self,favicon)
```

to

```
    self.SetIcon(favicon)
```

Also, try removing the 16's from the wx.Icon call and making sure your icon has other resolutions.